# What do you call the small cabin on top of roof of certain buildings?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the small cabin on top of roof of certain buildings?

[image]

The small cabin with something on top of it and with pipes running to the top of it. Is there a word for it? What are some standard ways of referring to that thing?

Comment: Does the *cabin* contain the stairs down to the rest of the building or is it standalone and only accessed from the other roof entrance/exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical term for these structures seems to be either *house* or *bulkhead* (e.g. *stair/elevator house* or *stair/elevator bulkhead*), but satisfactory online definitions are hard to find.

> **bulkhead**
>
> 3. a boxlike structure built over an opening, as at the head of a staircase, elevator shaft, etc.

[Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/bulkhead)

> **Elevator house or bulkhead** Structures with elevators may have an equipment or motor room located on the roof. Elevator houses vary in size according to the number of elevators that they service...

[Fire Engineering's Handbook for Fire Fighter I and II](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i4bmE2TqY6sC&pg=PA338&lpg=PA338&dq=%22elevator+house+or+bulkhead%22&source=bl&ots=4Yz1wFoU2W&sig=ACfU3U3cmZeDwK1Jxg0mXMEWR5ZbKHbJrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIkPzZzu_jAhWBSEEAHecqAh0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22elevator%20house%20or%20bulkhead%22&f=false)

The term *elevator house* may well be more understandable than *elevator bulkhead* to the average person.

Comment: "The term elevator house may well be more understandable than elevator bulkhead to the average person." Agreed. As a native speaker, when I hear "bulkhead" I immediately think of a ship. I would never have associated that word with a structure like this.

Comment: *Bulkhead* appears to be a common architectural term, and has lots of different uses. Basically, it's just an access space above some other structure.

Comment: @Mick  Which country are we talking about? Whilst not an architect, I've never heard "bulkhead" used in that context in the UK. Both the [online OED Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bulkhead) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulkhead) define it as a partition or wall to divide two spaces, not the space itself.

Comment: Look at the last definition in your MW link.

Answer (score 3):

If it contains air conditioning, lift (elevator) motors and similar equipment then it could be called the "**plant room**". Although a plant room is not confined to the roof of a building, it may be anywhere, such as the basement.

Answer (score 0):

Roof tower, this is just a stair well with a small landing at top of stairs inside.

Comment: Please note that you can edit answers, instead of posting a new one ...

Answer (score 0):

Or Stair tower, can be used to name the structure.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].